# How to print wavemon output to a .txt file?

Tags: python, linux

I'm searching for any way to save the wavemon program output to a .txt file?

Something like:

```
sudo wavemon -d | grep -i signal >> wavemon.txt
```

I'm not getting it at all. I'd like to save the output as a 'snapshot'... that way I could take the program's output and use it within code...

To install wavemon:

```
sudo apt install wavemon
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, wavemon uses a terminal manager called ncurses so it doesn't output to stdout as normal so you unfortunately won't be able to pipe this to another command properly. I would recommend using another tool that is a standard command line tool like `iwconfig`. For example:

```
iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"wsiit"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 20:AA:4B:A3:63:39   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:218   Missed beacon:0
```

You should be able to grep `Signal level` from this command.